# serving hierarchical static content with spray

Tags: java, javascript, scala, tomcat, spray

I have a hierarchy as follows

```
--> myexample.war
  --> WEB-INF
  --> web
    --> admin
      --> index.html
      --> js
        --> somejs.js
```

What should be my spray route to be able to serve it? (need to use spray).

I tried

```
  val webRoute = path("web") {
    get {
      entity(as[String]) {
        thePath =>
          complete(getFromResourceDirectory(thePath))
      }
    }
  }
```

getting:

```
> error: could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller:
> spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller[spray.routing.RequestContext
> => Unit]
```

but it does not seem to be correct, how should I be using it to be able to serve any file from within the **web** directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are just missing an import statement.  Possibly this one:

```
import spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller
```

**Edit**

Nevermind.  The getFromResourceDirectory doesn't need to be in a complete:

```
  val webRoute = path("web") {
    get {
      entity(as[String]) {
        thePath =>
          getFromResourceDirectory(thePath)
      }
    }
  }
```